# Testing a Container (Singleton)

Tags: perl, testing

I have the following piece of code for a given Base.pm module:

```
use Application::Container;

my $container;

sub container {
    unless ( defined($container) ) {
        $container = Application::Container->instance;
    }
    return $container;
}

sub configuration {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return $class->container->get('Application::Base');
}

sub log {
    my ($class) = @_;
    $class->container->get('Application::Log');
}

# and many more similar subroutines
...
```

Where Application::Container is an object container module, like [Micro::Container](http://search.cpan.org/~xaicron/Micro-Container-0.03/lib/Micro/Container.pm).

How do I write a test code for this Base.pm module?

**Why would you need to test that?**

I don't know but for every `.pm` and `.pl` file in my application I am supposed to have a corresponding `.t` test code.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. How do I write test code? Well, you open your editor and press keys on your keyboard? What is the specific problem? Testing a Singleton? Perl-testing in general?

Comment: @innaM testing a singleton. mmm, for example when I call $configuration =  Application::Container->configuration(); and print it with Dumper I get all the content of 'Application::Base' module, and I dont know how to compare expected value and obtained value, i tried: ok ( $configuration->isa('Application::Base'), "and it's the right class" ); but it tells me it can't call the method on unblessed reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Test::More;
use Application::Container;

my $test_container = $Application::Container::container;

is($test_container,undef,'container is not defined');

my $test_container = Application::Container->container();
my $test_container_singleton = $Application::Container::container;

ok($test_container,$test_container_singleton,'container is good');
```